# PrimeFaces CommandButton is not working in Dialog

Tags: primefaces, dialog, commandbutton

I need your help in solving the issue with the `CommandButton` in the dialog as I am calling a method called `UpdatePrint()` in the action and it is not called. The jsf page code is as follow:

```
<h:form id="Requests">
.
.
.
<p:commandButton update=":Requests:#{hr.dialogueName}" oncomplete="PF('#{hr.certificateDialogue}').show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="View">
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{hr}" target="#{hrd.selectedRequest}"/>
</p:commandButton>
.
.
<p:dialog header="cert1" widgetVar="cert1" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="true">
<p:outputPanel id="HRCEEN" style="text-align:center;">
</p:outputPanel>
 <p:commandButton value="Print" action="#{hrd.UpdatePrint}" type="button" icon="ui-icon-print"  style="display:block;margin-bottom: 20px">
<p:printer target="HRCEEN"/>
</p:commandButton>
</p:dialog>
.
.

<p:dialog header="cert2" widgetVar="cert2" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="true">
<p:outputPanel id="HRSSEN" style="text-align:center;">
</p:outputPanel>
<p:commandButton value="Print" action="#{hrd.UpdatePrint}" type="button" icon="ui-icon-print"  style="display:block;margin-bottom: 20px">
<p:printer target="HRSSEN"/>
</p:commandButton>
</p:dialog>

</h:form>
```

I tried different ways, but I wasn't successful with them as it showed me that the section in the update is not found when I am referring in the update.

```
 <p:commandButton update=":Requests:#{hr.dialogueName}" oncomplete="PF('#{hr.certificateDialogue}').show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="View">
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{hr}" target="#{hrd.selectedRequest}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action method is not called because of the `type="button"` attribute - there is no submit to the server. Remove `type`, then the action will be triggered (the button will assume the default `submit` type).

Comment: This is true for any commandButton with `type="button"`, not specifically in dialogs